# How to apply datediff function in select statement using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure to select columns of tables like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSelect
AS
BEGIN
SELECT ID, CheckIn, 
LapsedDay = CASE WHEN Checkout = NULL THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, CheckIn, GETDATE ()) ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, CheckIn, CheckOut) END, CheckOut FROM TblGuest 
END
```

whenever I am executing this query, it isn't showing any error but it's not calculating the the datediff in LapsedDay column in ms SQL. Any help related to this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try Checkout IS NULL instead of Checkout = NULL

Comment: I tried using IS NULL, but no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= NULL` is not correct.  Comparisons to `NULL` almost always return `NULL`.

Just simplify the logic using `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT ID, CheckIn, 
       DATEDIFF(DAY, CheckIn, COALESCE(CheckOut, GETDATE()) AS LapsedDay,
       CheckOut
FROM TblGuest
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it's just amazing... Your answer enlightened me and I come to know the beauty of this function. Thanks once again...